# How to install unity 3d on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation

According to [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unity3D) the only thing that I need to install is [unity-editor](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/unity-editor/). After I run `unity-editor` I get:

[image]

When I follow the link, I get to https://store.unity.com/download and the official site says `Unity is available for Windows or Mac OS X`. There's no Linux-based package.

Comment: Unity Hub is also in the AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/unityhub/  Also: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-hub-v-1-6-0-is-now-available.640792/

Comment: Yeah, I also needed to install unity hub, it wasn't clear to me for the first time, as I thought unity hub is to download the unity, and it's required to apply the license...

Answer (score 1):

It's an [AppImage](https://appimage.org/), so after you have made sure all [listed dependencies](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/unityhub/) are installed, you download the [Unity 3d file](https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/UnityHubSetup.AppImage), put it where you want it, go there (preferably in the path), and make it executable with

```
$ chmod a+x unityhub-2.0.2.AppImage
```

then launch it.

```
$ ./unityhub-2.0.2.AppImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install this package from AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/unity-editor-bin/.

There is no need to install any dependencies, it works out of the box.